# Using group by in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table creation scripts:

```
CREATE TABLE assetcost(
assettype VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
rentamt INT
);

CREATE TABLE furnishitem(
itemid VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(itemid LIKE 'I%'),
description VARCHAR(30),
availablesets INT,
assettype VARCHAR(25),
specialCharge CHAR(1) CHECK(specialcharge IN ('Y','N')),
FOREIGN KEY(assettype) REFERENCES assetcost(assettype)
);

CREATE TABLE custdetail(
custid VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY CHECK(custid LIKE 'C%'),
custname VARCHAR(30)
);


CREATE TABLE transaction(
transid INT UNIQUE,
custid VARCHAR(5) ,
itemid VARCHAR(4),
sets INT,
days INT,
amount INT,
returned char(1) Check (returned in('Y','N')),
FOREIGN KEY(custid)REFERENCES custdetail(custid),
FOREIGN KEY(itemid)REFERENCES furnishitem(itemid) 
);
```

I am getting error when writing query to display the custid and custname of those customers who has/have paid minimum of total amount, irrespective of the item returned.

My query is:

```
select t.custid,c.custname
    -> from transaction t inner join custdetail c
    -> on t.custid=c.custid
    -> group by t.custid
    -> having sum(amount)=(select min(sum(amount) from transaction group by custid);
```

Comment: In an RDBMs, *every* table should, in principle, have a PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to solve this in a more elegant fashion, but a quick fix to your problem would be:

```
SELECT t.custid, c.custname
FROM TRANSACTION t
INNER JOIN custdetail c ON t.custid = c.custid
GROUP BY t.custid
HAVING sum(amount) = (
    SELECT sum(amount)
    FROM TRANSACTION
    GROUP BY custid
    ORDER BY 1 ASC 
    LIMIT 1
    );
```

You can't really do `min(sum(amount))` in a single go. This approach will get you the row with the sum for the custid with minimum value.

Comment: Thanks Filipe. The above solution works well for me. Could you please explain why the following query gives ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function:select custid,min(sum(amount)) from transaction group by custid; In oracle it is working fine but giving error in MySql.

Comment: It's the MIN(SUM(abount)). You can't do both MIN and SUM at the same time. You would have to do first the sum and group by custid, and then find the MIN from those in an outside query.